# Angular get Http get one instance from observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a problem few of my components need same data from backend. So they all calls getDataMethod(); it looks like this

```
public getData(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<any>(this.backendUrl);
}
```

response come in 5 seconds during this time I approximately call this method 3-4 times. So my question is were any they to return same observable to multiple subscribers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could publish the response as a replaySubject like so

```
public getData(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<any>(this.backendUrl)
                .publishReplay(1)
                .refCount();
}
```

this will replay the results from the server without making a call to your api endpoint each time someone subscribes to the observable.

Comment: `shareReplay(1)` is shorter.

Answer (score -1):

you can use a "cache" variable.

```
data:any
public getData(): Observable<any> {
  if (this.data)
     return Observable.of(this.data);
  else
     return this.http.get<any>(this.backendUrl).do((data:any)=>
       {
           this.data=data
       });
}
```

Comment: This will still cause multiple requests if you subscribe while the request hasn't finished.